# Does google track content duplicacy if same article is written in company blog or somewhere else?

Tags: duplicate-content

I see some articles are submitted in multiple sites(medium.com,company blog).

Does Google track duplicate content for the same company?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate content is duplicate no matter how you sugar coat it.

Google and other search engines treat duplicate content in the order they are discovered, this means the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th etc, will be marked as duplicate. This won't necessary hurt the sites that host these articles unless they have a high volume of duplicate content on the site.

If you have backlinks on these articles then they are likely to hurt you too because they are duplicate on several sites and because Google has a good understanding of self-generated backlinks on a range of public blogging platforms.